# Why did Ethiopia not fight for the coastline of Eritrea when giving them independence?

Tags: africa

It is kind of crazy to me that Ethiopia wouldn't just take that slither of Eritrea that connects them to the coast. They were bigger and could easily have done it when giving them independence.

Just to add: With Eritrean independence, Ethiopia became the world’s most populous landlocked country.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on History.SE

Comment: I'll post it on History. I didn't know. Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: The author [reposted the question on history.se](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/56571/why-did-ethiopia-not-fought-for-coast-from-eritrea-when-giving-them-independence). Questions should only be active on one site of the Stack Exchange network, so I am closing this incarnation.